# Bash - Sort a list of strings

Tags: bash, list, sorting

Would you please show me know how I can sort the following list (ascending oder A to Z) (or a list in general) with Bash?

I have been trying but still could not get the expected results:

```
my_list='a z t b e c'
```

And the result should be a list as well, as I will use it for Select Loop.

```
my_list='a b c e t z'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you been trying? Show your attempts.

Comment: Do you need the list to be a string? Can't you use arrays?

Comment: @PesaThe The input output are lists. For an array, I can get it sorted with Bubblesort.

Comment: @HungTran You can use arrays for `select` loop as well. You don't need a "string" list.

Comment: @lurker OP most likely means the `select` keyword.

Comment: @lurker and @PesaThe, yes it is `select loop` in Bash

Answer (score 16):

You can use xargs twice along with a built in `sort` command to accomplish this.

```
$ my_list='a z t b e c'
$ my_list=$(echo $my_list | xargs -n1 | sort | xargs)
$ echo $my_list
a b c e t z
```

Answer (score 8):

If you permit using the `sort` program (rather than program a sorting algorithm in `bash`) the answer could be like this:

```
my_list='a z t b e c'
echo "$my_list" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ' '
```

The result: `a b c e t z'`

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are more suitable to store a list of things:

```
list=(a z t b "item with spaces" c)

sorted=()
while IFS= read -rd '' item; do
    sorted+=("$item")
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${list[@]}" | sort -z)
```

With `bash 4.4` you can utilize `readarray -d`:

```
list=(a z t b "item with spaces" c)

readarray -td '' sorted < <(printf '%s\0' "${list[@]}" | sort -z)
```

---

To use the array to create a simple menu with `select`:

```
select item in "${sorted[@]}"; do
    # do something
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and [controling array traversal order with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning):

```
$ echo -n $my_list |
  awk 'BEGIN {
      RS=ORS=" "                            # space as record seaparator
      PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"  # array value used as order
  }
  {
      a[NR]=$0                              # hash on NR to a
  }
  END {
      for(i in a)                           # in given order
          print a[i]                        # output values in a
          print "\n"                        # happy ending
  }'
a b c e t z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
my_list=($(sort < <(echo 'a z t b e c'|tr ' ' '\n') | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/ $//\
'))
```

This will create `my_list` which is an array.

Comment: Note that `array=( $(...anything...) )` is not great practice; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29)